# What is the difference between electron and electron-prebuilt?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, electron, npm-install

Saw many times that package name, but did't get when do I need to install it instead of common `electron`...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The short answer is if you want to write an Electron app today you should forget `electron-prebuilt` ever existed and always install the `electron` package instead.

The long answer is that there used to be an NPM package called `electron` that was completely unrelated to Electron, so the Electron team had to use another name to distribute Electron on NPM, hence `electron-prebuilt`. Later on the author of the `electron` package kindly transferred the name to the Electron team so that they could publish Electron under that name, and put an end to people accidentally installing the wrong package.

Comment: Wow I never heard of this anywhere, cool fact, I was always curious about this. I just assumed that the default Electron package was un-built and was just source code, so they used electron-prebuilt to give you the full application

Comment: If you're curious (as I was) why they chose "prebuilt" as the suffix to use, it's explained here: https://electronjs.org/blog/npm-install-electron